# How can I get g++ 7+ on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, g++

I have just installed g++ using MinGW. When I tried `g++ --version` it says, that it is 6.3.0:

```
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I get g++ 7 or newer?
**Edit**: I am using Windows 10 home 32-bit (on x64 CPU, but 2GB RAM) version 1909 OS build 18363.1440

Comment: Cygwin has g++ 7.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get g++ 7 or newer?

The simplest way would be to download the appropriate release of [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/ray_linn/GCC-10.X-with-ada/).  The release you downloaded was last updated in [2012](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mingw-builds/downloads).  You will want the i686 (32-bit) archive.  There are other [sources](http://winlibs.com/) for compiled versions of MinGW though.

[MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/)

Source: [How to update GCC in MinGW on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865319/how-to-update-gcc-in-mingw-on-windows)

You probably want [this](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases/tag/10.2.0-11.0.0-8.0.0-r8)

Answer (score 1):

Since you computer is 64-bit capable, I would suggest upgrading Windows from
32-bit to 64-bit. Activation should be automatic by digital entitlement
(hardware fingerprint).
The only caveat is that there is no in-place upgrade path to make the switch,
making a clean installation of Windows 10 the only viable option.

Upgrading Windows to 64-bit will allow you to install the
[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux),
where you may choose among several real Linux distributions, and be able to install
any package from their official repositories, including g++ 7.

I just note that Windows 10 64-bit will run better with at least 4 GB of RAM,
as 2 GB are not recommended.